# convert stdClass object with XML data to array in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, type-conversion

Given this object:

```
stdClass Object (
    [customerdata] => <TPSession userid="22" CustomerId="123456"LoginId="123456"/><TPSession userid="26" CustomerId="1234567"LoginId="1234567" />
)
```

How can I convert this XML data to an array using PHP?

Comment: what should the array look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply cast it to array:

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
```

Comment: Useful but isn't the solution for original question.

Answer (score 1):

Xml data in the question is not valid.

1. It has no root element
2. CustomerId="1234567"LoginId="1234567" breaks xml parsing

You need to wrap it into root element , resolve attribute issue, than you can use simple xml parser to generate object that can be converted to array.

Example

```
$o = new stdClass ();
$o->customerdata = '<TPSession userid="22" CustomerId="123456"LoginId="123456" /><TPSession userid="26" CustomerId="1234567"LoginId="1234567" />';
function wrap($xml) {
    return sprintf ( '<x>%s</x>', $xml );
}
function fix($xml) {
    return str_ireplace ( '"LoginId', "\" LoginId", $xml );
}

$xml = wrap ( fix ( $o->customerdata ) );
$sx = new SimpleXMLElement ( $xml );
$sx = ( array ) $sx;
$sx = $sx ['TPSession'];
foreach ( $sx as $row ) {
    var_dump ( ( array ) $row );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to convert the string contained into the object element to an array, in other words, convert an xml string to an array.

This is what you looking for...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Follow the example on this page.